# order by a string with number and letter

Tags: sql, string, numbers, letter

I want to order by a string in sql that have number in it and I want orderby number as number instead of string
these are sample string

[image]

I try this but it does not work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM testTbl
   ORDER BY REPLACE(code,' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question or your example.

```
 SELECT *
FROM testTbl
ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(code, '[0-9]+') AS NUMERIC_ORDER);
```

Comment: Hi Raul
my data is a string with leter, number and special char like '/'. 
I want order these rows. for example :
AC8
AC12
but now when I order this col, the result is:
AC12
AC8

Comment: Then you should separate the numeric part from the string characters and sort by the two fields, by casting the numeric part to a number.                                  
 SELECT columna
FROM testTbl
ORDER BY 
  SUBSTRING(code, 1, 2),
  CAST(SUBSTRING(code, 3) AS UNSIGNED);